# TSQL - Executing CLR Permission

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlclr, database-permissions

I got a sql procedure from a CLR (.net Assembly) that when executed returns an error

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_HelloWorld, Line 0
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user defined routine or aggregate 'sp_HelloWorld': 
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
System.Security.SecurityException: 
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
   at System.Security.PermissionSet.Demand()
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.DemandPermission()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at HelloWorld.SQLCLR.HelloWorld()
```

This is my SQL script

```
go
drop procedure HelloWorld
drop assembly HelloWorld
GO

create assembly HelloWorld from 'F:\HelloWorld.dll'
with permission_set = safe
Go
create procedure sp_HelloWorld
as external name HelloWorld.[HelloWorld.SQLCLR].HelloWorld
go
exec sp_HelloWorld
```

and this is my Class (Assembly)

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Data;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class SQLCLR
    {
        [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
        public static void HelloWorld()
        {
            string connectString1 = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ItemData;Integrated Security=True";

            SqlClientPermission permission = new SqlClientPermission(PermissionState.None);
            permission.Add(connectString1, "", KeyRestrictionBehavior.AllowOnly);
            permission.PermitOnly();
            SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectString1);
            sqlcon.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Top 1 * FROM ItemData.dbo.Item", sqlcon);
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
            SqlContext.Pipe.Send(reader);
            sqlcon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Juvil, if you are still interested, I have added an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32341040/577765) that explains the issue and corrects the code for best practices. I have also explained why the other answers don't work (in comments on those answers).

Answer (score 7):

The problem is simply that you are attempting to access an external resource in an Assembly that is marked as `SAFE`. Accessing external resources requires setting the Assembly to at least `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` (and in some cases `UNSAFE`). However, looking at your code, you are simply trying to connect to the local instance, and in that case there is a far easier (and faster) means of doing this: using `"Context Connection = true;"` as the ConnectionString.

The Context Connection is a direct connection to the current process / session, and it is sometimes referred to as the in-process connection. The benefits of using the Context Connection are:

- can be done in Assemblies marked as `SAFE`
- access to local temporary objects (temp tables and temp procedures, both with names starting with a single `#` instead of double `##`)
- access to `SET CONTEXT_INFO` and `CONTEXT_INFO()`
- no connection startup overhead

Also:

- whether you use the in-process, Context Connection or a regular / external connection, you do not need to formally request permission using `SqlClientPermission`
- you should always clean up external resources by calling their `Dispose()` method. Not all objects have this, but `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, and `SqlDataReader` certainly do. It is typical for people to wrap disposable objects in a `using()` block as it is a compiler macro that expands to a try / finally structure that calls the `Dispose()` method in the `finally` to ensure that it is called, even if an error occurs.
- The `Dispose()` method of many / most disposable objects automatically handles the call to `Close()` so you usually do not need to call `Close()` explicitly.

Your code should look as follows:

```cs
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void HelloWorld()
{
  using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("Context Connection = true;")
  {
    using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Top 1 * FROM ItemData.dbo.Item",
               sqlcon))
    {
      sqlcon.Open();

      using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
        SqlContext.Pipe.Send(reader);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great info... it make so much sense to have this.  But!  One more important thing we need.....  test for where-are-we-running to choose between this and a typical string so we can use the typical connection string at design-time.  How do we test if we have this "sql server Context"?

Comment: Just found exactly the answer...also written by you :).   Maybe you could add the link...  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31279625/1518460

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add my two sense to this. I'm doing something very similiar and I'm getting the same error. Here is what I found, however b/c I don't have this level of access to the DB I can't test it.

> Easiest( although not MSDN recommended just to jet a CLR proc to run) 
>   is to set the permission level to External_Access...
>
> SQL Server Host Policy Level Permission Sets The set of code access
>   security permissions granted to assemblies by the SQL Server host
>   policy level is determined by the permission set specified when
>   creating the assembly. There are three permission sets: SAFE,
>   EXTERNAL_ACCESS and UNSAFE.
>
> The permision level is set on the properties pages of the CLR project
>   , database tab -  set Permission Level-External, set Aassembly
>   Owner-dbo,  and run tsql 'ALTER DATABASE DataBaseName SET TRUSTWORTHY
>   ON' This will get the job DONE! - and the SmtpClient wiill work ok...
>   Then do it right and Sign the Assenbly with a Strong name Key file...

[Full Post Here...](http://forums.asp.net/t/981172.aspx/1)

Comment: Given that the desire is to connect to the local instance, this is certainly not the easiest or even best approach. And setting the database to TRUSTWORTHY ON, while being quick and easy, is a bad approach that is usually unnecessary. True, the last statement does say "then do it right...", but if someone gets it working with `TRUSTWORTHY ON`, then there is very little chance that they will come back to do it right later. Either way, I explain the real issue in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32341040/577765).

Answer (score -4):

Have you set your DB set to Trusrtworth ON and enabled clr?

Try this

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabase] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
GO
```

I have a guide [here](http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/09/06/execute-stored-procedures-in-parallel/) on how to use CLR Stored Procedures that might help.

Comment: This didn't help fix it for me.

Comment: @Ryan and Raymund: these steps won't help. If CLR wasn't already enabled, then attempting to run any SQLCLR code would error stating that CLR Integration has not been enabled. Setting the DB to TRUSTWORTHY ON, while quick and easy and usually helps for EXTERNAL_ACCESS or UNSAFE assemblies, it is usually unnecessary as it presents a security risk. The issue here is that the assembly is set to SAFE which disallows any external requests. Step 1 would be to set the Assembly to EXTERNAL_ACCESS, but there's an even better option as I shown in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32341040/577765).

Comment: I agree this is not really on-point.  The issue is the permissions.  The other comment and other answer get to the heart of the matter.