# Best way to handle connection when calling a function from a Console App or SQLCLR object with ("Context Connection=true")

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I have the following type of code in my data layer, which can be called from a console app, windows app, etc, with the proper connection string being read from the corresponding caller's App.Config file:

```cs
public static udsDataset GetDataset(int datasetID)         
{
   string connectionString = 
             ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
   string sql = @"select * from Dataset WHERE DatasetID=@datasetID";

   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
      // Dapper query:            
      return conn.Query<udsDataset>(sql, new {datasetID } ).First();
   }    
}
```

I now want to call this same code from a SQLCLR stored procedure (within the database where these tables exist), where you would typically use a [context connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131053%28v=sql.120%29.aspx):

```cs
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true")) 
{
    connection.Open();
    // etc etc etc
}
```

The most obvious approach that comes to mind is to overload the function:

```cs
public static udsDataset GetDataset(int datasetID)
{
   string connectionString = 
       ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
      return GetDataset(datasetID, conn);
   }
}

public static udsDataset GetDataset(int datasetID, SqlConnection conn)         
{
    // caller is responsible for closing and disposing connection
    string sql = @"select * from Dataset WHERE DatasetID=@datasetID";

    return conn.Query<udsDataset>(sql, new {datasetID } ).First();
}
```

So apps with an App.Config could call the connection-less version and SQLCLR could call the version requiring a SqlConnection.

This "seems ok", but having to write the exact same style of overload for every single similar function makes it feel wrong.

Comment: Why dont you write a metod  GetConnection() and use that one from all places where you are doing Using(sqlConnection conn = GetConnection()) {}  ?   the GetConnection metod should handle the connectionstring, so the rest of your code don't have to care about it.

Comment: Does that not *theoretically* lose the advantage of guaranteed connection disposal?  Regardless, I still need the option of passing in an existing connection when calling from a SQLCLR procedure.

Comment: no the method should create a new connection each call , and the Using() surrounding it is handling the disposal so no problem with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the question (and comments on it) at face-value, why do you need:

> the option of passing in an existing connection when calling from a SQLCLR procedure

? You should treat the `Context Connection` the same as any other connection with regards to `Open` and `Dispose`. It sounds like you are thinking that the `SqlConnection`, when using a Connection String of `"Context Connection = true;"`, needs to be opened only once and then not disposed until completely done, whereas you would `Open` / `Dispose` of it several times otherwise. I don't see any reason to have differing behavior in these two scenarios.

---

All of that aside, how to best handle detecting the change in environment (between Console App and SQLCLR object)? You have two choices, both being probably easier than you are expecting:

1. **Make *no* changes to the app code, but rely on an additional config file:**

   You can create a file named `sqlservr.exe.Config` in the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL{SqlVersion}.{SqlServerInstanceName}\MSSQL\Binn` folder (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn`, where the `11` in `MSSQL11` is for SQL Server 2012). The format of this file, as should probably be expected, is as follows:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
       <connectionStrings>
           <add name="CoolioAppDB" connectionString="Context Connection = true;" />
       </connectionStrings>
   </configuration>
   ```

   This *might* be considered "cleaner" code, but does introduce an external dependency that your DBA might be ok with, might dislike but tolerate, or might ask your manager to write you up for ;-).
2. **Make a very *minor* change to the app code, but don't rely on an additional config file:**

   You can easily auto-detect whether or not you are currently running in SQL Servers's CLR host by using the [IsAvailable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlcontext.isavailable.aspx) property of the `SqlContext` class. Just update your original code as follows:

   ```cs
   string connectionString = "Context Connection = true;"; // default = SQLCLR connection

   if (!SqlContext.IsAvailable) // if not running within SQL Server, get from config file
   {
     connectionString = 
               ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CoolioAppDB"].ConnectionString;
   }
   ```

   This usage, by the way, is noted in the "Remarks" section of that linked MSDN page for the `IsAvailable` property.

Comment: Option #2 seems most attractive, but either I didn't explain well or I'm misunderstanding something.  The DLL containing GetDataset() may or may not be running within SQL Server, it may be just deployed to a regular windows desktop.  Do I just have to add "using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server" to that class and then I'm good????   So if SqlContext.IsAvailable == true then use: connectionString = "Context Connection = true;" and if not, read the connection string from the config file (and this would only occur when NOT running in SQL Server, so I WOULDN'T need the config installed in Sql Server)

Comment: Assuming it's true I just need to add that "using", then this logic can just be encapsulated in a GetConnectionString function and the individual methods then won't need to have any knowledge of this, beautiful.

Comment: @tbone Answering your first comment here: Yes, that is exactly what Option #2 is all about. Just add `using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;` so that you can test for `SqlContext.IsAvailable`. The code that I posted would work regardless of where the DLL was installed. Again, this exact use-case is advocated in that MSDN page in the "Remarks" section. And so to your second point: Yes, you could encapsulate this into a generic `GetConnectionString` method. Oh, any yes, tis beautiful :-).

Comment: Excellent, thanks once again @srutzky, seems like you answer half my questions! :)